# Why does JsonConfigurationSource throw FileNotFoundException when file clearly ought to exist?

Tags: c#, configuration, filenotfoundexception

Consider the following C# code:

```
var json = "{ \"LogLevel\": \"Debug\" }";
const string filePath = @"C:\temp\tempconfiguration.json";
File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
var jsonConfigurationSource = new JsonConfigurationSource { Path = filePath };
var jsonConfigurationProvider = new JsonConfigurationProvider(jsonConfigurationSource);
var configuration = new ConfigurationRoot(new List<IConfigurationProvider> { jsonConfigurationProvider });
```

When I run this, it throws:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
The configuration file 'C:\temp\tempconfiguration.json' was not found and is not optional.
```

That makes no sense to me. The file clearly exists (I can see it in Windows Explorer). Can anyone explain to me what goes on here? Thanks in advance!

(I know I can also use `JsonStreamConfigurationProvider` to read from a stream, but I *want* to be able to also read the configuration from a file. Mainly because `JsonStreamConfigurationProvider` does not support `IConfigurationRoot.Reload`.)

I am running .NET 5.0 and C# 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that `Path` is relative to `FileProvider` of `JsonConfigurationSource`. You can either set `FileProvider` explicitly:

```
var jsonConfigurationSource = new JsonConfigurationSource { Path = Path.GetFileName(filePath) };
jsonConfigurationSource.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
```

Or easier way, call `ResolveFileProvider`:

```
var jsonConfigurationSource = new JsonConfigurationSource { Path = filePath };
jsonConfigurationSource.ResolveFileProvider();
```

Which will automatically create `FileProvider` from your absolute path AND make that path relative after that (so will do the same as above for you).

Comment: You are right! What a horrible API! (Or at the very least, what a horribly bad error message.)